# Add both listeners and text formatting to TableRow

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, onclicklistener, factory

I have a class `JobTable` which extends `TableView`. The `TableView` has a *drag and drop* feature from the following code:

```
setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<Job> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
        if (!row.isEmpty()) {
            Dragboard db = row.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(Integer.toString(row.getIndex()));
            db.setContent(content);
        }

        event.consume();
    });

    row.setOnDragOver(event -> {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        if (db.hasString()) {
            int draggedIndex = Integer.parseInt(db.getString());
            if (draggedIndex != row.getIndex())
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
        }

        event.consume();
    });

    row.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        if (db.hasString()) {
            int draggedIndex = Integer.parseInt(db.getString());
            Job draggedItem = getItems().get(draggedIndex);

            int dropIndex = (row.isEmpty()) ? this.getItems().size() : row.getIndex();
                
            reIndexJobs(draggedIndex + 1, dropIndex + 1, draggedItem.getCategoryProperty().getValue());

            event.setDropCompleted(true);
            refreshDataModel();
            getSelectionModel().select(dropIndex);
        }

        event.consume();
    });

    return row;
});
```

Code works fine. I later wanted to add some formatting so I wrote the following code afterwards:

```
setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Job>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Job job, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(job, empty);
            
        System.out.println("Checkpoint");
            
        if (job == null)
            setStyle("");
        else if (job.isOnHold())
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: #baffba;");
        else
            setStyle("");
    }
});
```

This also worked correctly. However at the moment I can only `setRowFactory` to either one or the other. I tried to combine both features by extending `TableRow` in an inner class declared in `JobTable`:

```
public class CustomTableRow extends TableRow<Job> {
    public CustomTableRow() {
        super();            
        
        setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                Dragboard db = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(Integer.toString(getIndex()));
                db.setContent(content);
            }

            event.consume();
        });

        setOnDragOver(event -> {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            if (db.hasString()) {
                int draggedIndex = Integer.parseInt(db.getString());
                if (draggedIndex != getIndex())
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
            }

            event.consume();
        });

        setOnDragDropped(event -> {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            if (db.hasString()) {
                int draggedIndex = Integer.parseInt(db.getString());
                Job draggedItem = getItems().get(draggedIndex);

                int dropIndex = (isEmpty()) ? getItems().size() : getIndex();            
                
                reIndexJobs(draggedIndex + 1, dropIndex + 1, 
                        draggedItem.getCategoryProperty().getValue());

                event.setDropCompleted(true);
                refreshDataModel();
                getSelectionModel().select(dropIndex);
            }

            event.consume();
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Job job, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(job, empty);

        if (job == null) 
            setStyle("");                        
        else if (job.isOnHold()) 
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: #baffba;");                        
        else 
            setStyle("");
    }
}
```

Then set the row factory to the new `CustomTableRow` class: `setRowFactory(tv -> new CustomTableRow());`

The formatting works, but I've lost the drag and drop feature. I'm fairly new to functional programming so I'm struggling a bit...

Comment: I see no reason that wouldn't work. Create and post a [mre].

Comment: Note also that in JavaFX 20 and later, you could implement the formatting with `row.itemProperty().map(Job::onHoldProperty).orElse(false).addListener((obs, wasOnHold, isOnHold) -> row.setStyle(isOnHold ? "-fx-background-color: #baffba;" : ""));`, which would avoid the need for subclassing `TableRow` and could be combined with the original implementation of drag and drop. (Still no reason your suggested approach doesn't work, though.)

Comment: I tested this out as best I could without a reproducible example, and it worked just fine. If it’s not working, the problem almost certainly lies in code you haven’t posted

Comment: A more generic solution to styling the on hold jobs would be to use a style class or psuedoclass, similar to how the default tableview row styling styles odd and even rows.  But that is not really the issue with the code you have, so I won't elaborate on it here.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I genuinely didn't think I could write minimal reproducible code because I thought the underlying problem was my lack of understanding of functions, lambdas and Callbacks. Because I was told it *should* work I went back to basics and rewrote the code from scratch and it does indeed work. I haven't really identified what the original problem was.